# How can I make an ubuntu bootable USD for a Mac, using a Windows PC?

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10, macbook

Ok, so I have a Macbook Pro (Late 2009) which had OS X Lion on it, i went to format the Macbook and it now no longer allows me to install OS X Lion on it. So i have a Macbook with no working OS on it. So I figured I'd attempt to install Ubuntu on it, however I need to make the bootable USB stick using the Windows PC, since I can't do anything on the Macbook.

Comment: @PatrickNegus: OP is asking how to create a bootable USB drive ***for* Macbook Pro **on** Windows*. I don't see how installation instructions for Macbook Air are helping here. The linked question doesn't address this issue either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Ubuntu
2. Get a USB of at least 2GB size
3. Use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or similar program to create a bootable USB stick

Go [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for Ubuntu official help.

Comment: @Patrick Negus, The question is how to make a `bootable usb` not how to install on a `mac`. And that is what I put here from `ubuntu official page`

Comment: No, he needs to create a bootable USB stick on Windows to install Ubuntu *on the Mac*.

Comment: @PatrickNegus, yes I know but he only asked how to create a disk, although he mentioned what he wanted it for he did not ask. Thats why i wrote my answer. if it was the other I won't have said a thing as I have no exprience using mac

Comment: Ok, I concede your point.